# Selecting a SSD for Fusion Drive

Tags: ssd, performance, fusion-drive

My aging Early 2009 Macbook White is getting a bit long in the tooth, so  after learning about Fusion Drive, I'm considering combining the existing 500GB HDD with a budget-to-medium-class SSD drive, to prolong the life of the machine.

As far as I understand, Fusion Drive will fill up the drive to within 4-5 GB of its capacity.

In other news I read that some mainstream SSD controllers (eg. Sandforce) have very poor write performance when the disk is used to its full capacity.

So my questions are:

Is the "fullness" of a Fusion Drive SSD considered "full capacity" in the context of controller performance degradation?

Which aftermarket SSDs are supposed to perform consistently fast in the Fusion Drive scenario? So far I have looked at Samsung 840, OCZ Vertex 2, Agility 3, Intel 330, based on a combination of price, brand reputation and reviews - but several of them are Sandforce drives.

Thirdly, does it make sense to create an empty 8-10 GB partition on the SSD before creating the Fusion Drive, to keep the drive from filling up? And is it even possible to create a Fusion Drive on a partitioned SSD?

Cheers!

Comment: As you have multiple questions, please consider actually making this multiple questions. One would be concerning the brand of the SSD, the other would be about creating a Fusion Drive on a partitioned SSD. This keeps things organised and will help more people in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is pretty close to "full capacity" (the first 117 of 128 GB [are filled](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6679/a-month-with-apples-fusion-drive/3)), but SSDs do overprovisioning for this reason.
2. As long as you have [enabled TRIM](http://www.groths.org/?page_id=322) on your SSD, you should be fine. I keep my (non-Fusioned Crucial RealSSD 300) SSD near full capacity and don't experience degradation, as long as I have TRIM turned on (if it's turned off it gets terrible fast).
3. Yes, you can create a Fusion Drive by specifying the partitions, e.g.:

   diskutil cs create fusion /dev/disk0s2 /dev/disk1s2

If you are looking for non-Sandforce controlled devices, you have many options now: Crucials M4/M500, Samsung SSDs, OCZ Agility/Vertex 4, and more.

For further reading, check out [AnandTech's article](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6679/a-month-with-apples-fusion-drive/3) with more details and pretty graphs.